# update postgres column with joined table values with double conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to update in postgres a column "nome" in TABLE A using "nome" values from TABLE B with A.lid=B.loc ?
I think I'd need to update before rows with A.lotto=1 and then A.lotto=2 but I don't know how.
Please help me, thanks in advance

TABLE A

```
+----+-----+-------+------+
| id | lid | lotto | nome |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 1  | 1   | 1     | null |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 2  | 2   | 1     | null |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 3  | 3   | 1     | null |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 4  | 1   | 2     | null |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 5  | 2   | 2     | null |
+----+-----+-------+------+
```

TABLE B

```
+-----+-----+------+
| mid | loc | nome |
+-----+-----+------+
| 5   | 1   | a    |
+-----+-----+------+
| 6   | 2   | b    |
+-----+-----+------+
| 8   | 3   | c    |
+-----+-----+------+
| 8   | 1   | d    |
+-----+-----+------+
| 9   | 2   | e    |
+-----+-----+------+
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
+----+-----+-------+------+
| id | lid | lotto | nome |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 1  | 1   | 1     | a    |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 2  | 2   | 1     | b    |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 3  | 3   | 1     | c    |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 4  | 1   | 2     | d    |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 5  | 2   | 2     | e    |
+----+-----+-------+------+
```

Comment: What does the column `lotto` have to do with your requirement? Post your expected output to clarify what you want.

Comment: a territory is divided in two parts (lotto 1 & lotto 2). In each part (aka "lotto") there are some polygons in table A with their own and unique progressive id (lid) and I need to update their name taking it from another non-spatial table B where are listed and named all different zones in both parts.

Comment: You need a unique key to make you update work perfectly. b.loc is not unique.

Comment: Is a.lotto = b.mid ?

Comment: too easy, @Philippe (I know it would be simpler):
Isn't there a way to update "nome" column value only in some rows in table A ?
Expected output would be:

+----+-----+-------+------+
| id | lid | lotto | nome |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 1  | 1   | 1     | a    |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 2  | 2   | 1     | b    |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 3  | 3   | 1     | c    |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 4  | 1   | 2     | d    |
+----+-----+-------+------+
| 5  | 2   | 2     | e    |
+----+-----+-------+------+

Comment: No, a.lotto <> b.mid

Comment: @ocelot73 can you post add the expected result to your question? we can barely read it here :)

Comment: If you 'on't have a key in table a to join table b I think that it will be possible.

Comment: @ocelot73 any luck with the query?

Answer (score 0):

Just place the second table in the `FROM` clause and join the columns you want, e.g.

```
UPDATE a SET nome = b.nome
FROM b WHERE a.lotto = 2 AND a.lid = b.loc
AND b.mid NOT IN (     
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (lid) mid FROM a,b
  WHERE a.lotto = 2 AND a.lid = b.loc);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a1034755d5bf381120a488a97ad0285a)

Comment: b.loc is not unique key. Your join will not work

Comment: I could have duplicates in this way..that's not correct. I have to distinctly update lotto 1 and lotto 2 geometry names

Comment: I've tried with:

UPDATE a
SET nome = b.nome
FROM b
WHERE b.loc=a.lid AND a.lotto=1

then repeated with a.lotto=2 but I have duplicated names not associated to their lottos

Comment: @ocelot73 see my update: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a1034755d5bf381120a488a97ad0285a